# como alterar o <h2> para <h1> via jquery

Tags: jquery

Preciso alterar o h2 para h1 dinamicamente pensei usar jquery da seguinte forma mas nao funciona:

```
$("h2").removeAttr("h2").attr('h1');


$("h2").attr('h1');
```

usando classes como seletor;

```
$(".wd-product-list .wd-widget .wd-title").Attr("h1");
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito utilizando a função [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), segue um exemplo:

```js
$('h2').replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<h1>" + $(this).html() + "</h1>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>H2</h2>
<h2><span>H2 span ola</span></h2>
```

*Nota que tu está tentando trabalhar com atributos (`attr`) e tanto o `<h1>` quanto o `<h2>` são [**tags** usadas para definir cabeçalhos HTML.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)

---

**Update**: Com base [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another) do **SOen**, descobri uma forma interessante de chegar no mesmo resultado, segue o snippet:

```js
$('h2').contents().unwrap().wrap('<h1/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>H2</h2>
<h2><span>H2 span ola</span></h2>
```

Comparei a performance das duas através do [jsperf](https://jsperf.com) e constatei que a primeira solução utilizando a função `replaceWith` é mais eficiente.

Segue o link do teste efetuado: [JsPerf - Replace Tag](https://jsperf.com/replace-tag/1).

Comment: A entendi creio que esse foi o motivo que não funcionou. Seguindo a logica que usei não existe uma forma mais simples de fazer isso? menos código, apenas uma pergunta para aumentar meu conhecimento. E nao conhecia as tags que usou de jquery [replaceWith]. A principio obrigado

Comment: Não conhecia esse `jsPerf`, muito interessante.

Comment: @hyperpixel Acredito que essas formas já estejam enquadradas no grupo de soluções simples para esse problema, com certeza existem outras, mas não vai mudar muito pois o código já está bem simplificado.

Comment: @Isac eu conheci não faz muito tempo também, em alguma resposta aqui do SO mesmo, é bem bacana.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer também da seguinte forma:

```js
$('#botaoAlterarTag').click(function() {
  $('h2').contents().unwrap().wrap("<h1 class='titulo'>");
  $('.titulo').load();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="titulo">Título</h2>
<input type="button" id="botaoAlterarTag" value="Alterar título">
```

Observe que, ao clicar no botão, a `tag` do texto em questão passa de `h2` para `h1` e, em seguida, é dado um `refresh` na `tag` que possui `class` denominada 'titulo' através do método `load()` do jQuery para exibir o texto com a nova `tag`.
Esse exemplo fiz com o evento `click`, mas você pode utilizar outro evento de acordo com a sua necessidade.